# Emacs Window Resize on Startup

Tags: emacs

So I have been using emacs a lot lately. And I have been noticing that the window resizes for a second when it starts up. Is there a way to fix that?

Here is the [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORwsw.jpg) of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Are you specifying the window dimensions in your .emacs file?

Comment: No. In my .emacs files there are no window dimension specification. And I also tried to comment out my window location specification but still no luck at all. Please help me.

Comment: What happens if you run `emacs -Q`?

Comment: It opened up a scratch pad buffer. Surprisingly, it behaved differently. So I think that when I open emacs with my configuration, it takes a while to load which is why it does that resizing thing. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, that's quite likely, but it suggests that you *do* have something in your .emacs file that is resizing your window.  Take another look.  (Look for geometry and font specifications too.)

Comment: The initial shape of Emacs without any user-configuration is mostly square-looking, and it looks like you have modified it to change to a rectangle.  Emacs loads first with a default frame size -- it's possible to modify the source code and there a few threads on the internet that talk about that, but most people don't go through the trouble.  I think there are some window manager settings on Linux that I have read people use to try and control the initial frame size, but I don't use Linux.  Google for things like `initial-frame-alist` and `default-frame-alist`.  If not already, use Emacs 25.

Comment: Emacs 27 should have a way to do this in Lisp, look into `early-init.el`.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent Emacs from resizing its window after startup, put all geometry and font options on the command line or `.Xdefaults` file rather than in `.emacs` or other lisp init files.

The initial Emacs frame is drawn before running the lisp startup files, but the X config and command line options have already been read.

As your GIF is mainly showing a width change, with only a minor change in height and no change in the position of the frame, I suspect it is most likely font settings rather than size settings that you need to look for.

Comment: where can I find .Xdefaults?

Comment: .Xdefaults can be created in your $HOME directory if you use X. The documentation for what to put there can be found in the [Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Resources.html) If you are not using X, there may be another way you can set the initial geometry and font, check the Emacs manual, FAQ and other resources.

Answer (score 2):

My Sample Code **(Ensure to put these codes at the first line of your init.el file)**

```lisp
(setq frame-inhibit-implied-resize t) ;; prevent resize window on startup
(setq default-frame-alist '((width . 120) (height . 42)))
(defun x/disable-scroll-bars (frame)
  (modify-frame-parameters frame '((horizontal-scroll-bars . nil)
                                   (vertical-scroll-bars . nil))))
(if (display-graphic-p)
    (progn
      (scroll-bar-mode -1)
      (tool-bar-mode -1)
      (fringe-mode '(8 . 0))
      (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'x/disable-scroll-bars))
  (progn
    (menu-bar-mode -1)
    (setq-default
     left-margin-width 1
     right-margin-width 0)))
```

The core is `(setq frame-inhibit-implied-resize t)`.

Comment: Only doing `(setq frame-inhibit-implied-resize t)` did not make any difference for me, but explicitly resizing with just the line `(setq default-frame-alist '((width . 120) (height . 42)))` helped .

Answer (score 0):

I've got this line in my `.emacs` to go fullscreen on startup:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))
```

Comment: This kind of worked, but created a full-screen-sized window that was not full-screen. And as that was not what I wanted, I exchanged `full-screen` with a size as in @Color's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I run Emacs from WSL with an X11 server on Windows 10. I could set some `-geometry` to make it *not* resize into a minimal initial window, but that seemed to be flaky and random. This happened with both `Xming` and `Vcxsrv`. It happened even with `-Q` so in my case it was not related to anything in my startup files.

I haven't tried Cygwins X11 server, but when I tried the evaluation version `X410` (available in the Windows Store) it did not have the same problem.